# What algorithm do SVMs use to minimize their objective function?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, simplex

Support Vector Machines turn machine learning linear classification tasks into a linear optimization problems.

$$ \text{minimize } J(\theta,\theta_0) = \frac1n \sum_1^n \text{HingeLoss}(\theta,\theta_0) + \frac{\lambda}{2} ||\theta||^2 $$

My question is, what linear programming runs on the background for the minimization of the objective function $J$. Is it Simplex?

Comment: Its not linear programming. its Quadratic programming, you have here a quadratic function and not a linear one

Comment: A good algorithm to use is the SMO - Sequential Minimal Optimization, which is a technique specifically designed for SVMs

Comment: @nirshahar Thanks a lot. I recommend that you post those comments as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SVM problem (and other related problems) can be described as a minimization \ maximization of a quadratic function.

This can be easily solved with the [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) algorithm, however I recommend using the [SMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization) algorithm since it is a direct solution (to the dual of the SVM problem), and can be also used for kernelized SVMs

Comment: Addition to the above answer: I just came across this paper (link below) that presents PEGASOS algorithm. It claims that with PEGASOS "the number of iterations required to obtain a solution of accuracy $\epsilon$ is $O(1/\epsilon)$, where each iteration operates on a single training example. In contrast, previous analyses of stochastic gradient descent methods for SVMs require $Ω(1/\epsilon^2)$ iterations" https://courses.edx.org/assets/courseware/v1/16f13f7ac37ae86ebe0372f2410bcec4/asset-v1:MITx+6.86x+1T2021+type@asset+block/resources_pegasos.pdf